# MariaDB column datatype DATE got converted to DATETIME datatype

Tags: mariadb

When I try to add a new DATE datatype column to my table, it gets automatically converted (see attached screenshot) to DATETIME datatype, is there some sql setting I must disable to prevent this?

MariaDB version is 10.6.11.

```
MariaDB [mydb]> describe my_table;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_date DATE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.010 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [mydb]> describe my_table;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| my_date | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> show create table my_table;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                               |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my_table | CREATE TABLE "my_table" (
  "id" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  "my_date" datetime DEFAULT NULL
) |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ORACLE,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: I don't see this: https://dbfiddle.uk/i--1cPCk   can you do a `show create table my_table` and `select @@sql_mode`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ysth I've updated the output for those query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the ORACLE SQL mode; temporarily remove that while you do your alter table:

```
set session sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'ORACLE','');
alter table ...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7WnlHO0h)

Comment: may I know if there are any implications on removing the 'ORACLE' sql_mode?

Comment: Just changing it for your session will not affect any other database connections.  In general it has a lot of weird effects intended to make porting from oracle easier; see the documentation